# Android datepicker dialog title pillarboxed

Tags: android, styling, datepickerdialog

I'm trying to style the datepicker dialog. So far I managed to change the background and button color. But as you can see in the image below, the title is sort of 'pillar-boxed'.

My datepicker dialog with the dark boxes left and right of the title:

[image]

My xml code so far (values/styles.xml)

```
 <style name="PickerDialogTheme_dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorBackground_bgreen</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonColor</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonColor">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorBackground_bgreen</item>
</style>
```

In java it is just a regular datepicker dialog constructor with the theme set to PickerDialogTheme_dark and I'm trying to get this to work on pre Lollipop versions.

So hope you guys know how to get rid of this pillar-boxed title. If possible without using fragments and all in xml would be favourable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it finally after searching some more on the internet!

How my final xml code looks now:

```
<style name="PickerDialogTheme_dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/DialogBackground_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogBackground_dark">
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/colorAccent_bgreen</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/colorAccent_bgreen</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/colorAccent_bgreen</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/colorAccent_bgreen</item>
</style>
```

[This is how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JA6c.png)